# Executar Videos com parâmetros

Tags: python

Pessoal estou tendo dificuldades na criação de um script relativamente simples.

Tenho alguns arquivos .mp4 e queria tentar executa-los em ordem (com loop) e em Full Screen

Estou com esse código:

```
class Video(object):
    def __init__(self,path):
        self.path = path

    def play(self):
        from os import startfile
        startfile(self.path)

class Movie_MP4(Video):
    type = "MP4"

movie = Movie_MP4(r"C:\\Users\\Empathy.co\\Desktop\\Bot\\Olhos_Animado.mp4")

movie = Movie_MP4(r"C:\\Users\\Empathy.co\\Desktop\\Bot\\Olhos_Animado_Parte01.mp4")



movie.play()
```

Ele executa somente o ultimo video e não tenho ideia de como fazer para deixar em full screen e em loop (tentei usar o While True porém aparentemente ele não reconhece que o processo já foi aberto e fica abrindo sem parar)

Comment: Vide documentação: "*startfile() returns as soon as the associated application is launched. There is no option to wait for the application to close, and no way to retrieve the application’s exit status.*"

Answer (score 1):

A chamara `os.startfile` tem exatamente o mesmo efeito que você clicar no arquivo pela interface gráfica. Ou seja: o sistema operacional vai abrir o programa associado em primeiro lugar com aquele tipo de arquivo - e, depedne do programa se vai sair reproduzindo o vídeo ou não.

Mas  `os.startfile` não deixa você escolher nenhuma opção, nem sequer deixa você escolher qual programa você vai usar.

O que você vai precisar nesse caso é sabe qual prorama quer chamar para reproduzir os filmes, (por exemplo: "vlc player"), e estudar na documentação desse programa quais parâmetros você pode passar na linha de comando para ativar as opções desejadas (full screen, e etc...) - e aí chamar o programa, com a opções e o caminho para o arquivo usando as opções do modulo `subprocess`.

Por exemplo:

```
 subprocess.run(["mplayer", "-fs", movie])
```

Se o tocador de vídeo for o mplayer. Isso vai passar a opção "-fs" pra ele e o caminho do vídeo. Quando o vídeo for cocnluido, o mplayer se encerra e o seu programa continua na próxima linha.

O que nos leva a outra parte da sua pergunta: só um vídeo é reproduzido porque você está usando duas vezes a mesma variável  - quando você cria a egunda variável `movie` contendo um objeto da sua classe `Movie_MP4`, o primeiro é "esquecido", e deixa de existir.

E por fim, você está fazendo uma lambança com os caminhos para os arquivos. *ou* você usa o prefixo `r"` para as strings, ou duplica as "\", digitando cada uma como "\".  Fazer as duas coisas, até funciona, mas é bem feiinho.

O ideal mesmo seria criar os caminhos de arquivo como instâncias de `pathlib.Path` - e usar a "/" que é usada universalmente, fora do Windows, para separar arquivos e diretórios. No ponto onde for passar o caminho do arquivo para o `subprocess.run` você usa `str(nome_do_arquivo)` para converter o Path para string.